# Linking Drop Down List to an Array

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

I have created an array to feed a Google Sheet from entires in a Google Form. The function for the array is

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1r_0VSCu9r009_4.......ly6fMqpKeTjiXw","'Sort Test (New)'!A2:P100"),
 "SELECT Col2, Col8, Col4, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12, Col13, Col1",1)
```

It shows the following results in the sheet:

[image: Screenshot of the current output of sheet]

Everything is working except that when a new entry is added in the form, Column A is not bound to the array which starts in Column B. When a new entry is added the selected list item in Column A remains in place (Row 12) and the status becomes inaccurate each time a new entry is added.

I am trying to understand how to bind Col A to the rest of the array starting in Col B so that each time a new entry is added, the Status in Column A stays locked to that particular person and creates a full new row.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet? with example where it fails

Comment: Can't share as it relies on data from another sheet that is only accessible within our company drive folder. To be more clear, if I add another row of data above Mahesh with the entry of data from a new form entry, Yuhao slides down one row while his status does not and would go from coding interview to Withdrew under status. Does that help make it more clear?

Comment: well hard to tell like this but you should take a look on VLOOKUP function which is able to pair up two sets based on common column

Comment: I made a copy of the data in this sheet. If I add a row to responses, the funnel sheet will add a new record but not shift Column A down (A2 stays in place). Hence, A11 loses selected status from the dropdown list selection. I am looking to get A2 to be "In Process" each time a new row is added and the previously selected "Status" to move down. Code functions are in B2 on funnel and in A1 in Sorted Responses.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OySOlccLsMRG9cHYeNzZdJO2UnUtWcjx4YXmMZWlc2I/edit?usp=sharing

Thoughts?

Comment: answer and your sheet updated

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1OySOlccLsMRG9cHYeNzZdJO2UnUtWcjx4YXmMZWlc2I", "Response!A2:P"), 
 "select Col2,Col8,Col4,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col1", 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=QUERY('Candidate Funnel'!A1:J, "where J is not null order by J", 1)
```

[image: 0]

---

or reversed order:

```
=QUERY('Candidate Funnel'!A1:J, "where J is not null order by J desc", 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The point of the sort was to keep the most recent record on top (sorted by form completion date). Maybe that is not possible then? Basically, can I reverse the order?

Comment: you can use this formula for that `=QUERY('Candidate Funnel'!A1:J, "where J is not null order by J desc", 1)`